# Game Center is not working in iPhone 3GS iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, game-center

I have iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.0. and i am trying to connect using game center with other device but its not working and always Failed. But its working fine with iPhone 4 with iOS 4.0 and iPad.

So please can any one suggest me how i solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This is a computer support question, not a programming question, and belongs on another site like SuperUser rather than here. :)

Comment: I asked here bcoz i used the game center in my application and may be some problem in implementation. so....

Comment: At least show some code. How are we to know your question is programming-related otherwise?

Comment: Is Game Center working on this device for other third party games from other developers? Presuming you want to test your code on iOS 4.x, why not at least update the device to iOS 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

Game Center is a new social gaming network that is available on supported iOS-based devices running iOS 4.1 and later.

check the Apple documentation for that. here's the link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html